# jQuery Tab Menu Set Active Menu and load the content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `jQuery` tab menu call ajax.

Menu is working perfect, but now I want when page loaded it always show the first tab to be loaded (means active).

You can see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/rw8ujfg3/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up " id="friends">
  <li active><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843293/" data-target="#contacts" class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
  <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843301/" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
  <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843306/" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
```

```
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="contacts">

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane  urlbox span8" id="awaiting_request">

  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
var $this = $(this),
    loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
    targ = $this.attr('data-target');

$.get(loadurl, function(data) {
    $(targ).html(data);
});

$this.tab('show');
return false;
});
```

In this case, I want Contact content loaded on page loaded. How can set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#contacts_tab').trigger('click');` if you are allowed to use the id.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Just abstract the function, and bind it to the event, but also call it on load with the first tab selected to call it on. (**EDIT**: Sorry I got the spacing on your function wrong before because I mis-copied it. Also, tested it and changed a few things to work out a kink or two.)

```
function doAjaxStuff(event, tab) {
  var $this = tab || $(this)
    var $this = tab || $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
}

doAjaxStuff(null, $('.nav-tabs li:first-child a'))

$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(doAjaxStuff);
```

Comment: Not working, can you please try to update in the fiddle?

Comment: I copied this straight from the fiddle just now. Copy/paste and it should work! : ) (also updated the fiddle).